# Passing collections in scala actors

Tags: scala, actor

When I need to pass typed collections to an actor, I get an "unchecked" warning in my `react` method:

```
val actor = actor {
  loop {
    react {
      case a:List[String] => // do something
    }
  }
}
```

How can I work around this? I tried boxing collection in a separate class (but that is ugly and cumbersome), and just casting collection (`case a:List[_] => a.asInstanceOf[List[String]]`) after receiving it by actor is not type-safe and dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the JVM does not keep track of the type of generics, you can't know that a `List[_]` is a `List[String]` unless you examine every element and check that it is a string.  Your best bet is in fact to box the collection in a separate class.  It need not be so bad!

```
case class StringsBox(ls: List[String]) {}

//...
myactor ! StringsBox( List("these","are","strings") )

//...
react {
  case StringsBox(ls) =>  /* Now you have your List[String] */
}
```